# xlsxwriter & xlrd issue - xlsx file saved as ZIP on one machine, but with other first 4 bytes on another

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlrd, xlsxwriter

I'm using xlsxwriter with .xlsx files, because I intend to write huge data, that isn't supported by .xls and here is what I'm doing at first:

```
output_name = "MY_XLSX_LOG_FILE" + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S')) + '.xlsx'
xlsx_document = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output_name)
xlsx_document_sheet = xlsx_document.add_worksheet('sheet_1')
xlsx_document_sheet.write(0, 0, 'Col1')
xlsx_document_sheet.write(0, 1, 'Col2')
xlsx_document_sheet.write(0, 2, 'Col3')
xlsx_document_sheet.write(0, 3, 'Col4')
xlsx_document_sheet.write(0, 4, 'Col5')
xlsx_document_sheet.write(0, 5, 'Col6')
xlsx_document_sheet.write(0, 6, 'Col7')
xlsx_document_sheet.write(0, 7, 'Col8')
xlsx_document_sheet.write(0, 8, 'Col9')
xlsx_document.close()
```

Then I open it like this:

```
file_name = FindLastLog() #this finds it successfuly
xlsx_document = xlrd.open_workbook(file_name)
```

With me it works perfectly, but when I give it to someone else and he runs it on his machine(same OS, same locale), he gets this:

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '\x11MyName'
```

`'MyName'` - I have absolutely no idea how this is written in the xlsx file. The exception is raised in function `getbof` in function `open_workbook_xls`. On my machine, the code never enters there. At the place where it's checked if the first 4 bytes are `b"PK\x03\x04"`, mine checks true and branches to `xlsx.open_workbook_2007_xml`, while his branches to `xlsx.open_workbook_xls`. We're both on `Python 2.7` and I don't understand the exact same identical `xlsxwriter` script is writing a different file format. What could be causing this?

Comment: I find it extremely hard to believe that your colleague's script ever gets to `xlsx.open_workbook_xls`, since no published version of xlrd has such a thing. What I would believe is that he is getting `book.open_workbook_xls`. This is consistent with @jmcnamara's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your colleague probably has an older version of xlrd that doesn't support xlsx files. If they update to the latest version or the version you have it will fix the issue.

Comment: i'm the one who sent him the modules, they're identical

Comment: Think about this from the other way round. If everything is identical on both machines then you have to get the same results. So something is different. Since xlsxwriter cannot produce an xls file it has to be one of two things. The xlrd version or the xlsx file is actually corrupted in some way. Print out the module versions on both machines and also compare the xlsx file size and if you can the xlsx checksum.